# Enviar arquivo acima do permitido pelo servidor

Tags: php

Um cliente tem um sistema desenvolvido por PHP do qual através do upload envia arquivos PDF para o servidor. Funciona corretamente, porém alguns arquivos estão acima do permitido pelo servidor. Existe algum meio de enviar esse arquivo pelo sistema de upload com alguma funcão nativa ou não do PHP? Pois esses arquivos o cliente nos envia e subimos manualmente pelo FTP.

Feliz 2018 a todos!

Comment: Você pode especificar o tamanho máximo do post e o limite máximo do tamanho do arquivo em php.ini `post_max_size` e `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: Coloca aqui o código de envio desses arquivos. Deve ter um delimitador que é só alterar no próprio código

Comment: Olá Leo. Mas nao tenho acesso ao php.ini, haja vista que o servidor é remoto e não local.

Comment: Olá Pedro. O problema não está no PHP, pois arquivos inferiores ao limitado pelo servidor sobre tranquilamente.

Comment: @Fox.11 Tenho site hospedado na Locaweb em Linux e consigo alterar o php.ini normalmente.

Comment: Estou pensando em usar o `ftp_put()`, mas nunca usei essa função.

Comment: @Fox.11 como não tem acesso? Você deletou ele? kkk

Comment: Não Leo. Infelizmente o servidor que o cliente se encontra não permite termos acesso ao arquivo. Para isso temos que entrar em contato com eles e solicitar as mudanças, do qual já foram feitas.

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente o servidor do cliente permite alterar apenas algumas configurações básicas do PHP diretamente pelo CPanel, como por exemplo: Register Globals, Safe Mode, etc. Para isso tivemos que entrar em contato com o servidor e solicitar a mudança, levando em consideração que eles aumentaram de 10 MB para 64 MB, o permitido para servidores compartilhados.